If the distortion of a compact set $X\subset \mathbb{R}^n$ is less than $\frac{\pi}{2}$ then $\pi_1(X)=0$.
I am currently reading M. Gromov's "Metric Structures for Riemannian and Non Riemannian Spaces" and I am aiming to study Gromov-Hausdorff convergence, Asymptotic geometry etc. I am stuck in the proof of a result which states, "Let $X$ be a compact subset of $\mathbb{R}^n$. If $distort(X)<\frac{\pi}{2}$ then $X$ is simply connected."
Kindly see the proof at Page 11 of his book (otherwise I have to write a long proof).
My question is: How does $u(s+\frac{l}{2})=-u(s)\implies$ length of $u$ is at least $2\pi$ and how the following inequality holds?
$$||\frac{du}{ds}||^2\le \frac{1}{r(s)^2}\left(4-\left(\frac{dr}{ds}\right)^2\right).$$
I must tell that the rest of the proof as well as the earlier results for the proof are very clear to me. But I can not prove this part!, Can we calculate the derivative $\frac{du}{ds}$? Or we use some argument to bound its norm?
Thanks in advance.
